# number of binary sequences containing k 1's with no isolated 1's

Tags: co.combinatorics

Given *N* and *K*, we need to find number of binary sequence of length *N* containing exactly *K* 1-bit such that no 1's are isolated.

Reference: [A097230](https://oeis.org/A097230)

I have tried the dynamic programming approach:

$dp[N][K] =\sum_{i=1}^{N} dp[N - i - 1][K - 2] + dp[N - i - 3][K - 3]$

with base conditions of:

1. $dp[N][1] = 0$
2. $dp[N][2] = N - 1$
3. $dp[N][3] = N - 2$

But this approach is limit for a **smaller** *N* and *K* (~1000).

How to formulate or compute the same for larger *N* and *K* (~10^6)?

Comment: This is not a challenge for $~10^6$ but it seems to be a challenge for $~10^{10}$. -- (?)